# Create a Bingo Card in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

.

```
int randomNum, high = 0, low = -14, row = -1;
Boolean goAgain;
```

.

```
ArrayList<Integer> numberList = new ArrayList<>();

do {

        high = high + 15;
        low = low + 15;
        row = row + 1;
        goAgain = true;

        for (int colum = 0; colum < 5; colum++) {

            do {

                randomNum = (int) (Math.random() * (high - low) + low);

                containsNumber = numberList.contains(randomNum);

                if (containsNumber == false) {

                    numberList.add(randomNum);

                    bingoBoard[row][colum] = randomNum;

                    goAgain = false;

                }

            } while (goAgain = true);
        }
    } while (row != 4);
```

I'm trying to create a Bingo Card. When I run the code above I get stuck in an infinite loop in the most-inner do-while statement. I know its probably an easy fix but I seriously cannot see the problem...

Comment: while (goAgain = true); should be while (goAgain); or while (goAgain == true);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning `true` to `goAgain` in this line:

```
} while (goAgain = true);
```

The operator `=` is the assignment operator.  So the inner do-while loop will never end.

You could compare `goAgain` to `true` with the `==` comparison operator, but `goAgain` is already a `boolean`, so you can just use the value itself.

```
} while (goAgain);
```

Comment: good one, I didn't notice either :D deleting my other answer.